# binding Records on UI Asp.net faster client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net, kendo-grid

i have Million of records into database and i want to bind that data on the UI in tabular Format.  the Problem is screen becomes white and data is not displayed at Gridview is applied there.so i want to remove that control and want to bind it using client side technology . what need to choose  ?

Comment: Problem is not with the control as per say really. The issue is too much data, how much data are you trying to bind in a go? have you implemented some sort of client side/ server side paging? are you using ajax to load the data? if not you need to consider these scenarios

Comment: within a update panel gridview is used there and on button click data is displayed and this is and existing page where more updatepanel and control are used .  gridview  server side  paging is  implemented.

Comment: There isnt any UpdatePanel in MVC. Are you using MVC or traditional asp.net?

Comment: asp.net webform